# Java - streaming big file from server to browser via spring mvc controller

Tags: spring-mvc, memory-management, inputstream, heap-memory, outputstream

```
@GetMapping("/")
@ResponseBody
public void getInvoice(@RequestParam String DocumentId,
                       HttpServletResponse response) {

    DocumentDAO documentDAO = null;
    try {
        documentDAO = service.downloadDocument(DocumentId);
        response.setContentType("application/" + documentDAO.getSubtype());
        IOUtils.copy(documentDAO.getDocument(), response.getOutputStream());
        response.flushBuffer();
        documentDAO.getDocument().close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The task is to stream pdf document from back-end server (a lot of big documents, up to 200 MB) to the browser via SpringMVC controller. Back-end server outputs document in InputStream - I am copying it to response OutputStream.

```
IOUtils.copy(documentDAO.getDocument(), response.getOutputStream());
```

And it works. I just do not like java memory consumption on machine, where this SpringMVC is running.

If it is streaming - why memory consumption increases very high, when customer performs request to this mvc controller?

When big document (i.e. 100 mb) is requested - java heap size increases accordingly.

What I expect is - my java machine should use only some buffer sized amount of memory should not load document to memory, just stream it by.

Is my expectation wrong? Or it is correct and I should do something somehow different?

Thank you in advance.

Here is graph of memory increase when requesting 63MB document
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYeXv.png

and then repeating the request after a while

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5d3J.png

and then GC does its job at the end

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hg6Q6.png

Comment: Can you try copying with 
public static long copyLarge(InputStream input, OutputStream output, byte[] buffer) ?

With this method you can specify your own buffer which you can define as class field and instance it in constructor

Comment: thank you for this hint. It led me to this buffer size - now I see that my back-end service is returning InputStream with buffer size equals to file size. This way the whole document comes to my RAM. Think there is nothing much else to do.